# Configure Graylog dashboard widget to link to query

Tags: graylog, graylog3

I'm using a system that recently upgraded to Graylog3. In Graylog 2 dashboard widgets it was easy to click a button that looked like a "Play" triangle to dive into a query.

In Graylog 3 the widget looks like the image below and none of the options I've clicked on seem to get to the underlying query. If I edit the widget I can see the query and then go recreate it manually, but I just want a "one click" way to get to the underlying data so I can dig into it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `play` button in graylog widgets from version 3.2.3

https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.2/pages/changelog.html#graylog-3-2-3